# PHP XY chart with moveable dots

Tags: php, ajax, charts

I am trying to create a XY chart in PHP which can dynamically be changed by the user when he selects dots from it and moves them around.
Are there any libraries or frameworks which have that functionality?

Comment: That would be primarily more of a HTML/JS issue, with data supplied by PHP and AJAX methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a task for PHP. PHP is for server side tasks, and this is browser side, so you should be using JavaScript or another browser based language.

I had to do something very similar to this, and had great success using HTML5 Canvas and the [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) framework.